# bottom border on table is not appearing

Tags: html, css, styles, border

My table class is .bottom and I want the bottom of the table to be a solid black line, all the way across.  So I tried this:

```
<table style="border-bottom-color:#000000">
```

But that doesnt do it.  So I tried this in CSS:

```
.bottom td {border-bottom: 2px solid black !important;}
```

and now everything in the table has a black underline( links, td, image) and all I want is the table itself to has a solid black bottom border.  Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: What about `<table style="border-bottom: 2px solid #000000">`? Keeping in mind that it's always better to have that defined in a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bottom {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}
```

Comment: I swear I tried this before and it didn't work, but sure enough it did this time.  I must have had a type.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Note, if you tried .bottom table { .. }, as was my first inclination, it won't work, because .bottom is the class FOR THE TABLE itself, not a container containing a table.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did, hehe

Comment: @JeremyGoodell: Yes - to get only a `<td>` with the class `.bottom`, one would have to use `td.bottom`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having a similar issue with borders on tables not appearing, you also might want to make sure you have set `table {border-collapse: separate;}` otherwise the border won't display, even if it has been styled.

While this behaviour is default, if you are using a template (say, for an eDM), it may have been set to `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` somewhere in the predefined template styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and all I had to do was add some margin-bottom to the table attribute.

```
 table {
        table-layout: inherit;
        width:91.8%;
        font-family: $fontserrat;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```